# score stops at 5 some times, but other times it will just keep going. How to fix this

Tags: javascript, function

When running this function the first few times, it will work and display if I won the game or not when the score hits 5. But other times the score will keep incrementing (6, 7, 8, and so on). Why does the score not stop at 5 sometimes, and how do I stop this from happening?

```js
    const playerText = document.querySelector("#playerText");
const computerText = document.querySelector("#computerText");
const resultText = document.querySelector("#resultText");
const choiceBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".choiceBtn");

let player;
let computer;


let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;



choiceBtns.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    player = button.textContent;
    computerSelection();
    playerText.textContent = "Player: " + player;
    computerText.textContent = "Computer: " + computer;
    resultText.textContent = "Result: " + result();
}));



function computerSelection(){

    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    switch(randNum){
      case 1:
        computer = "rock";
        break;
      case 2:
        computer = "paper";
        break;
      case 3:
        computer = "scissors";
        break;
    }
}

function disable() {
    document.getElementById("rock").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("paper").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("scissors").disabled = true;

  }



function result() {
    if ((player === "paper" && computer === "rock") || 
        (player === "scissors" && computer === "paper") || 
        (player === "rock" && 
            computer === "scissors" &&
            (computerScore <=5 && playerScore <=5 )))
        
        {
       
        playerScore += 1;
        resultText.textContent = ("You win! " + "Player score: " + playerScore + " Computer score: " + computerScore);
        
        return resultText.textContent;
        }
    
    if (playerScore == 5) {
        
        resultText.textContent = ("Winner winner chicken dinner! You won the game! " + " Player score: " + playerScore + "Computer score: " + computerScore);
        computerScore = 0;
        playerScore = 0;
        disable();
        return resultText.textContent;
        
    }
  

    
    else if 
        ((player === "rock" && computer === "paper") || 
        (player === "paper" && computer === "scissors") || 
        (player === "scissors" && 
        
            computer === "rock" && 
            (playerScore <=5 && computerScore <=5))
        
        
        ) {

        
        computerScore += 1;
        resultText.textContent = ("You lose! "+ "Player score: " + playerScore + " Computer score: " + computerScore); 
        
        return resultText.textContent;
    
    }
        if (computerScore == 5) {
        
            
            
            resultText.textContent = ("You lost the game!!!!! " + " Player score: " + playerScore + " Computer score: " + computerScore);
            computerScore = 0;
            playerScore = 0;
            disable();
            return resultText.textContent;

            
        }
    

    else (computer == player)
{
    resultText.textContent = ("Draw! " + "Player score: " + playerScore + " Computer score: " + computerScore);
    
    return resultText.textContent;

} 

}
```

When running this function the first few times, it will work and display if I won the game or not when the score hits 5. But other times the score will keep incrementing (6, 7, 8, and so on). Why does the score not stop at 5 sometimes, and how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: `(computerScore <= 5 || playerScore <= 5)` should probably be `(computerScore <= 5 && playerScore <= 5)` (in multiple places), to solve that particular problem.

Comment: I will suggest that you put your rock, paper and scissors values into an array or keyed object so you can simply compare relative rank rather than tracking a bunch of specific relationships.

Comment: @isherwood I have put edited my js code up you should see what i see now

Comment: @Steve I have tried that but getting the same error

Comment: You probably also need to group the previous statement (e.g. `player === "scissors" && computer === "rock"`) together in parentheses (e.g. `(player === "scissors" && computer === "rock")`)

Comment: @Steve still getting the same error when i add the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your `result` function:

```js
function result() {
  if (
    ((player === "paper" && computer === "rock") ||
      (player === "scissors" && computer === "paper") ||
      (player === "rock" && computer === "scissors")) &&
    playerScore + 1 <= 5
  ) {
    console.log({
      test: computerScore <= 5 || playerScore <= 5,
      computerScore,
      playerScore,
    });
    playerScore += 1;
    resultText.textContent =
      "You win! " +
      "Player score: " +
      playerScore +
      " Computer score: " +
      computerScore;

    if (playerScore == 5) {
      resultText.textContent =
        "Winner winner chicken dinner! You won the game! " +
        " Player score: " +
        playerScore +
        "Computer score: " +
        computerScore;
      computerScore = 0;
      playerScore = 0;
      disable();
    }
    return resultText.textContent;
  } else if (
    ((player === "rock" && computer === "paper") ||
      (player === "paper" && computer === "scissors") ||
      (player === "scissors" && computer === "rock")) &&
    computerScore + 1 <= 5
  ) {
    computerScore += 1;
    resultText.textContent =
      "You lose! " +
      "Player score: " +
      playerScore +
      " Computer score: " +
      computerScore;

    if (computerScore == 5) {
      resultText.textContent =
        "You lost the game!!!!! " +
        " Player score: " +
        playerScore +
        " Computer score: " +
        computerScore;
      computerScore = 0;
      playerScore = 0;
      disable();
    }
    return resultText.textContent;
  } else {
    resultText.textContent =
      "Draw! " +
      "Player score: " +
      playerScore +
      " Computer score: " +
      computerScore;

    return resultText.textContent;
  }
```

Your conditions:

```js
if ((player === "paper" && computer === "rock") || 
        (player === "scissors" && computer === "paper") || 
        (player === "rock" && 
            computer === "scissors" &&
            (computerScore <=5 && playerScore <=5 )))
```

There's no need to check the `computerScore` if only the score for the player will be affected by the player winning a round. Same applies to the inverse of this if statement.
Also, the score will exceed 5 because you are checking `computerScore` and `playerScore` before incrementing them. You can either add the increment value (in this case `1`) in the if statement or you could add a nested if statement after the increment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too messy, please refactor the code, after that find your bug later.

```
> Compute the result
> If player win set playerPoint++;
> else set computerPoint++;
// draw, go to new game.

> Check the winner
> if playerPoint >= 5 --> show message;
> else if computerPoint >=5 --> show message;

> end. go to new game.
```

Your code stop because you `return` too soon.

Comment: noted, what should i put instead of return then?